# Is the embedding of $W^{2,p}$ onto $C^1(\overline{I})$ compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

We know that when $I$ is a bounded interval and $1<p\leq \infty$ that the injection $W^{1,p}\subset C(\overline{I})$ is compact.

The proof of this fact uses the Arzela-Ascoli theorem on the unit ball $\mathcal{H}$ of $W^{1,p}(I)$. Is it true that the embedding of $W^{2,p}$ onto $C^1(\overline{I})$ is also compact?

**Please Comment on This Part**

Suppose that $u\in W^{2,p}$ then $u'\in W^{1,p}$ and thus $u'\in C(\overline{I})$
and therefore $u\in C^1(\overline{I})$.

Now let $\mathcal{H}$ be the unit
ball in $W^{2,p}$. Then $\mathcal{H}$ is equicontinuous since for all 
$u\in \mathcal{H}$,
$$|u(x)-u(y)|=\left|\int_{y}^xu'(t)dt\right|\leq \|u'\|_p|x-y|^{1/p'}\leq 
|x-y|^{1/p'}.$$
Hence by Ascoli-Arzela, $\mathcal{H}$ has compact closure in $C(\overline{I})$.
Since $\mathcal{H}\subset C^1(\overline{I})\subset C(\overline{I})$ then 
$\mathcal{H}$ has compact closure in $C^1(I).$ Is there anything wrong with the argument?

Comment: The norm in $ C^1 $ is different from $ C $. I doubt on the assertion that $ \overline{\mathcal{H}} $ is compact in $ C^1 $ since it is compact in $ C $ and belongs to $ C^1 $.